# jQuery: if element gets loaded with ajax event?

Tags: jquery, ajax, events

weird question. I'm trying to extend a little plugin that's in my blog's sidebar. The plugin comes with a bit of Ajax. It contains a form and when it's submitted it loads a d`iv#error_msg` or a `div#success_msg` (all through ajax).

Is there a way for me to find out when one of this divs appear? Just so get what i want: I want to prepend a text to the form in the sidebar when the form gets submitted. as soon as one of the two divs (either error or success) get's loaded in that form, i want to remove the prepended element again.

Do you guys know a way to do that? I don't want to edit the source code of the plugin!

edit: checkMsg() not defined! Why?

```
var check = 0;

function showLoader() {
        $('#mc_signup_form').prepend('<span class="loading"> loading </span>');
        check = setInterval ( "checkMsg()" , 300 );
    }

function checkMsg() {
    if ( $('.mc_error_msg').length == 0 || $('.mc_success_msg').length == 0 ) {
        $('#mc_signup_form .loading').remove();
        clearInterval(check);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the only thing loading via ajax, or is there other stuff going on as well?

Comment: it's just ajax loading i guess? i'm not 100% sure. it send's an email address to a database and returns true or false.

Comment: Do you really need to remove the element? If not you could try binding to the form submit using jQuery's `live` and then add the element, or change the element if it already exists. I'm not sure if this would work due to the order the events might fire, but worth a quick try. http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: i don't need to remove it. hide() would do it as well! i just need to know when the ajax stuff comes in. the text should hide() or get removed as soon as something happens inside of this form.

Comment: I agree with Nate Pinchot on this one jQuery live will do the trick

    $('div#error_msg').bind('load', function() {
  // do something here.. prepend text or something
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the DOM in a timeout loop to see if it's there. Brutish but effective. You would be better off finding where the app makes the ajax call and tapping into the response handler directly.

Comment: thank you, i edited my post! what am i doing wrong? my browser keeps telling me checkMsg() is not defined. why not?

Answer (score 0):

The prepending you can do by simply modifying the form's onsubmit attribute, but the removing of the text is a little more tricky.

Using [JQuery's AOP Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/AOP) you can run custom events before or after any function.  If you can find the js function the plugin is using to add the div, you could remove your message after the function runs.

Depending on how the plugin's coded, there's likely a much cleaner way.  See what it's doing to trigger the adding of the div, there may be an opportunity for you to inject a callback.  Also, if you add the name of the plugin to the question, the community will be able to answer you more specifically.